# typedef'ing an enum does not make the enum-values visible

Tags: c++, enums

I have a class in which I have an enumeration, defined like this:

```
class X
   {
   public:
      enum Direction {DIR_LEFT, DIR_RIGHT};
   };
```

Now I want this enumeration to be reused in another class, like this:

```
class Y
   {
   public:
      typedef X::Direction Direction;
   };
```

As expected, using Y::Direction works correctly, e.g.:

```
void myFunction (Y::Direction dir)
{
}
```

But the values within the enumeration does not seem to be 'copied' together with the typedef.  If I write the following, I get compilation errors:

```
myFunction (Y::DIR_LEFT);
```

Instead, I have to refer to the original place of the enumeration again, like this:

```
myFunction (X::DIR_LEFT);
```

Which defeats my purpose of typdefing the enumeration.

The only solution I see is to move the enumeration out of class X, and putting it in another class (e.g. MyEnums), so it can be reused by X and Y (although they should still use MyEnums::DIR_LEFT and MyEnums::DIR_RIGHT), but at least the code does not depend on class X anymore.

Why are the enumeration values itself no exposed via the typedef?

Are there any other patterns to manage enumerations in different classes?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Unfortunately C++ doesn't introduce a new scope with an `enum` although C++0x is improving things.

Practically this means that you can't typedef an enum and get the enumerated values as well.

What you *can* do is use a nested struct with the name you want for the enum and typedef THAT.

```
class X
{
public:
    struct Direction { enum EnumType {LEFT, RIGHT}; };
};

class Y
{
public:
    typedef X::Direction Direction;
};
```

Now you can do:
`myFunction (Y::Direction::LEFT);`

The purpose of the nested struct is to create a "fake" scope to holld both the enum name and its values.

Comment: You probably should remove the `DIR_` prefix because it was an artificial "poor man's namespace": `struct Direction {enum {LEFT, RIGHT};};` - just a bit dirtier than the C++0x syntax `enum class Direction {LEFT, RIGHT};`

Answer (score 1):

Here is my understanding of how enums work in C++. (Or at least my observed behaviour of enums in Microsoft Visual C++.)

The enum keyword does not create a scope the same way that classes do.

The full name then for your enum 'Direction', is X::Direction. The values within that enum are still part of the class scope, so they are X::DIR_LEFT and X::DIR_RIGHT.

When you typedef the enum in another class, this does not change the scope of the values of the enum.

I suggest you put the enum inside a namespace in a header file if you want to share it in multiple locations.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the enum values to be members of both classes, the
solution is to define a separate class with the enum, and
inherit from it, e.g.:

```
class MyEnums
{
protected:
    ~MyEnums() {} //  Prevent delete through pointer to this class
public:
    enum Direction
    {
        DIR_LEFT,
        DIR_RIGHT
    };
};

class X : public MyEnums
{
    // ...
};

class Y : public MyEnums
{
    // ...
};
```

Users will see X::Direction, X::DIR_LEFT and Y::Direction,
Y::DIR_LEFT.  Of course, they'll still be able to pass
a Y::DIR_LEFT to a function expecting an X::Direction; to
prevent that, make MyEnums a template, with the derived class as
the template argument.

Comment: it certainly looks like a misuse of inheritance :/

Comment: @Matthieu M. For what definition of "misuse"?  It's a more or
less standard technique in C++ to use inheritance to share
declarations, see std::iterator, for example.

Comment: it's not because the standard does it that it's necessarily good. The `protected` destructor should protect from a number of issues, but still it's "weird", in the sense that I can now pass polymophically classes that are quite unrelated. The `typedef` seems a superior alternative here.

Comment: You can pass polymorphically types that are actually unrelated, but would you?  I've never seen anyone passing around references to std::iterator, and I don't see why this would be any different.  (I'm not sure that the typedef solution isn't superior, but it doesn't have the same effect.  You still can't write X::DIR_LEFT, for example.)

Comment: yes, the absence of scoping of traditional enums prevent uniform syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Anything shared by more than one class should be factored outside of the classes and perhaps into a parent class.

direction.hpp:

```
#ifndef DIRECTION_HPP
enum Direction {DIR_LEFT, DIR_RIGHT};
#endif
```

x.hpp:

```
#ifndef X_HPP
#include "direction.hpp"

class X
{
  Direction dir;
};
#endif // X_HPP
```

y.hpp

```
#ifndef Y_HPP
#include "direction.hpp"

class Y
{
  Direction dir;
};
#endif // Y_HPP
```

Comment: Aren't you now polluting the global namespace with your enum? The OP's version didn't have this problem.

Answer (score 0):

If the original declaration:

```
    class X
    {
    public:
      enum Direction {DIR_LEFT, DIR_RIGHT};
    };
```

is embedded in a large legacy code-base, then we might want a solution that does *not* change any existing uses of X::Direction. In that case, the rather ugly:

```
    class Y
    {
    public:
       typedef enum X::Direction Direction;
       static const enum X::Direction DIR_LEFT = X:DIR_LEFT;
       static const enum X::Direction DIR_RIGHT = X:DIR_RIGHT;
    }
```

works...

Definitely *not* recommended for new code, however!

Comment: True, except that if the original definition is changed (Left and right given different values, for example) then the code using class Y continues to work correctly.